# Android Activity Dialog Theme want Icon

Tags: android, android-activity

I creating an activity with an Dialog theme

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.app.sendActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```

I want to the dialog themed Activity to have an icon.

Here is part of the code to create the dialog:

```
//Setup Dialog Activity Parameters
this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
setContentView(R.layout.widget_dialog);
LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.x = -30;
params.height = 350;
params.width = 550;
params.y = -30;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);


Log.i(TAG,"In onCreate");
setContentView(R.layout.widget_dialog);
```

Layout of Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">"
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>
     <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnWidgetDialogCancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            />
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnWidgetDialogClose"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Close"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screen Shot

[image]

Comment: Do you necessarily need an `Activity`? Maybe a `DialogFragment` would suffice?

Comment: Why not make a custom dialog instead of this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Here's what you need**. In this you can set your height and width as you wish giving that dialog feel. Just add this in your onCreate():

```
Window window = getWindow();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        int width = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * 1);
        int height = (int) (metrics.heightPixels * .85);
        window.setLayout(height, width);
```

And in your manifest, in the application level, set the theme as;

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

This works great for me ...Should work for you too. :)

Comment: Also, by doing this, you wont loose any content like icon or whatever that's in your screen.